# c# callback from c dll, pointer arg to c# class

Tags: c#, c, callback, dllimport

Not sure exactly what to name my question but,

I have some C# code that accesses a C dll using DllImports.
In the C# code I have functions that are registered with and called by the C dll.
The C dll calls the functions passing a pointer to them.

I have it working using an IntPtr to represent the arg in the C# callbacks.

working callback method:

```
public static int test(IntPtr lua_State)
```

**Now the question:**

I would like the argument type to instead be a class with 1 IntPtr field, and instance methods that would operate on that IntPtr

so the new callback method would look like:

```
public static int test(Lua lua_State)
```

and the class would be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Lua
{
    IntPtr lua_State;

    //Some random methods...
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working, the callback is getting called, but the Classes IntPtr field is not getting the value passed and is instead 0.

Is there a way to get this to work?

**edit:**

Deriving from SafeHandle works, however I would prefer to do it without the safehandle class as I don't want/need any excess it adds, all I need is the pointer value to be put into the IntPtr field of my class.

Comment: With the first method definition, could you simply pass `Lua.lua_State` as an IntPtr ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the C dll is passing a pointer. The first method, the working callback, receives the pointer as an IntPtr, the class Lua does not exist in that example. I could take the IntPtr argument and make it into an instance of the Lua class if I wanted, but what I want is for the pointer that is passed from C to be directly translated into a class instance. I hesitate to say I want the pointer 'Marshalled' into the being a class because I think that might be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle this is make `Lua` derive from [`SafeHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class Lua : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid 
{

     private Lua() : base (true)
     {
     }

     override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
     {
         return NativeMethods.CloseHandle(this.handle); //Or how ever you would normally release the pointer when done
     }

     //Other methods that work on the pointer, it is accessed via "this.handle"

}
```

Comment: What exactly does deriving from safehandle do? The problem isn't that 0 or -1 is getting passed to the callback, the problem is that the value that is getting passed isn't being translated into the class's IntPtr field.

Comment: SafeHandle acts as a `IntPtr` but it also allows you to add additional methods just like you wanted to do. It also takes care of your cleanup for you when `Lua` goes out of scope if any cleanup needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you, I have gotten this to work, however I would really prefer to do it without SafeHandle as the only thing I actually need is for the pointer to be put into the IntPtr field.